# Alphabetize string with words and numbers

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector

I'm trying to figure out how to alphabetize a single string that contains both words and numbers. As you can see below, I've tried using `isdigit` but some of the numbers are negative so my code is always wrong. Also, my code splits the string into substrings which alphabetize separately, but I don't know how to alphabetize all of the words separately, put them back into their spots in the vector and then alphabetize all of the numbers separately, and put them back into their spots. Could someone help?

EDIT:

Sample input #1:

```
4 dog 1 -3 0 cat 3
```

Sample output #1:

```
-3 cat 0 1 3 dog 4
```

Sample input #2:

```
tom 4 0 9 kid pie 1
```

Sample output #2:

```
kid 0 1 4 pie tom 9
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
vector<string> numbers; 
string str;
string x;                   
getline (cin, str);
stringstream ss(str);
while (ss >> x){
   numbers.push_back(x);
}

if (numbers.size()==1){
    cout << numbers[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}

vector<int> results(numbers.size());
for (int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
    char *a=new char[numbers[i].size()+1];
    a[numbers[i].size()]=0;
    memcpy(a,numbers[i].c_str(),numbers[i].size());
    if(isdigit(*a)==0)
    {
        results[i]=1;
    } else{
        results[i]=0;
    }
}

int j=0;
while (j<numbers.size()){
    int k=j+1;
    while (k<numbers.size()){
        while (results[j]==results[k]){
            sort(numbers.begin()+j,numbers.begin()+k+1);
            k++;
        }
        j=k;
        k=numbers.size();
    }
    if(j==numbers.size()){
        for (int i=0; i<numbers.size();i++){
            cout << numbers[i] << " ";
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post sample inpout, expected output, and observed output.

Comment: Can you share sample input outputs? Need to be sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: `char *a=new char[numbers[i].size()+1];`  Why??

Comment: Just provided a few sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie to make a character with the element I want to figure out if it's a number or not

Comment: The sample output has made me more confused about the problem than I was. I don't see a pattern for where the words are supposed to be in relation to the numbers.

Comment: The words stay in the same spot as before but they're now alphabetized. The numbers are placed in numerical order as well.

Comment: @Jeremy Why didn't you just use `std::string`?  There is absolutely no need to do what you're doing.  In addition, you've introduced a memory leak. `string a = numbers[i];`

Comment: You can use `std::istringstream` to read the parts into two separate vectors `std::vector<int>`and `std::vector<std::string>`. Sort each vector then scan through the original string again to decide to select from the int vector or the string vector to rebuild a sorted version of the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My 2p.**

```
std::string alphabetize(const std::string& s)
{
    // string parts here
    std::vector<std::string> a;

    // integer parts here
    std::vector<int> n;

    // remember the order of the input types (true = integer, false = string)
    std::vector<bool> type_is_int_list;

    // wrap input in a stream for easy parsing
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    // somewhere to read each part into
    std::string item;

    // extract one space-separated part at a time
    while(iss >> item)
    {
        int i;
        if(std::istringstream(item) >> i) // is item an integer?
        {
            n.push_back(i);
            type_is_int_list.push_back(true);
        }
        else
        {
            a.push_back(item);
            type_is_int_list.push_back(false);
        }
    }

    // sort both string and integer vectors
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(n.begin(), n.end());

    // a place to rebuild the output from the input
    std::ostringstream oss;

    // keep track of where we are in each vector
    auto a_iter = a.begin();
    auto n_iter = n.begin();

    // element separator
    std::string sep;

    // scan originally-ordered list of types to rebuild positions
    for(bool type_is_int: type_is_int_list)
    {
        if(type_is_int)
            oss << sep << *n_iter++; // add next sorted number to output
        else
            oss << sep << *a_iter++; // add next sorted string to output

        sep = " "; // after first item need space separator
    }

    return oss.str(); // return the reconstructed string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I felt like this code was the most readable and easiest to follow!

Answer (score 2):

First you need a function that determines, whether a string is a number or not. Use `strtol` for this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // strtol

bool is_number( const std::string &str, long &num )
{
    char *p;
    num = strtol( str.c_str(), &p, 10 );
    return *p == '\0';
}
```

Use this function in a second function, which determines whether string `a` is less than string `b`.

```
#include <tuple>

bool sortFunc( const std::string &a, const std::string &b )
{ 
    long numA;
    long numB;
    bool is_a_num = is_number( a, numA );
    bool is_b_num = is_number( b, numB );
    return std::make_tuple( !is_a_num, numA, a ) < std::make_tuple( !is_b_num, numB, b );                                      
}
```

Use `std::sort`, to sort the strings int the `std::vector`

```
// include <algorithm> // sort

std::vector< std::string > numbers;
.... 
std::sort( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sortFunc );
```

An other solution would be to split the `vector` in two separate `vector`s. One for strings and one for numbers and to sort them separately:

```
std::vector< std::string > numbers;
....
std::vector< std::string > vStr;
std::vector< long > vNum;
for ( std::string &str: numbers )
{
    long num;
    if ( is_number( str, num )
        vNum.push_back( num );
    else
        vStr.push_back( str);
}
std::sort( vNum.begin(), vNum.end() );
std::sort( vStr.begin(), vStr.end() );
```

Use a `std::map` if you want to know the position of each string or number in the original `vector`.

```
#include <map>

std::vector< std::string > numbers;
....
std::map< std::string, size_t > mapStr; // map string to index of string in vector numbers
std::map< long, size_t > mapNum;        // map number to index of number in vector numbers
for ( size_t index = 0; index < numbers.size(); index ++ )
{
    long num;
    if ( is_number( numbers[index], num ) )
        mapNum.emplace( num, index );
    else
        mapStr.emplace( numbers[index], index );
}

for ( auto & pa : mapNum )
    std::cout << pa.first << " pos " << pa.second << std::endl;
for ( auto & pa : mapStr )
    std::cout << pa.first.c_str() << " pos " << pa.second << std::endl;
```

Of course you can use a single `std::map` with a comparator function too:

```
std::vector< std::string > numbers;
....
std::map< std::string, size_t, bool(*)(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) > mapN( sortFunc );
for ( size_t index = 0; index < numbers.size(); index ++ )
    mapN.emplace( numbers[index], index );

for ( auto & pa : mapN )
    std::cout << pa.first << " pos " << pa.second << std::endl;
```

You can use `std::tuple` as key for the `std::map` too:

```
std::vector< std::string > numbers;
....
std::map< std::tuple< bool, long, std::string>, size_t > mapTupleN;
for ( size_t index = 0; index < numbers.size(); index ++ )
{
    long num;
    bool is_num = is_number( numbers[index], num );
    mapTupleN.emplace( std::make_tuple( !is_num, num, numbers[index] ), index );
}
for ( auto & pa : mapTupleN )
{
    if ( !std::get<0>(pa.first) )
        std::cout << std::get<1>(pa.first) << " is number at position " << pa.second << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << std::get<2>(pa.first).c_str() << " is string at position " << pa.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only thing I see is that this code won't put the words/numbers back into the spots belonging to words and numbers, respectively.

Comment: @Jeremy  if you want to know the position of each string or number in th original vector use `std::map`. See the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to sort the elements as you read them in.

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
std::stringstream ss(input);
std::vector<std::string> sorted;

while (ss >> input)
{
    bool alpha = 0 < std::isalpha(input[0]); //if it is a word
    for (std::size_t i = 0, e = sorted.size(); i != e; ++i)
    {
        if ((!!std::isalpha(sorted[i][0]) == alpha) && (alpha ? (input < sorted[i]) : (std::stoi(input) < std::stoi(sorted[i])))) //if input is <
            std::swap(sorted[i], input); //exchange places
    }
    sorted.emplace_back(std::move(input)); //insert input at end
}
```

Each iteration of the `while` loop, it checks the first character to see if it is a letter. If it is a letter, it must be a word, otherwise it is a number. Then, for each previously scanned element, it checks if they are both the same type (letter/letter, number/number). In the case they are both words, it just compares them. If they are numbers, it uses `stoi` to convert them to integers and compares the result. If the comparison yields that `input` is less than the element, it swaps the element with `input`. By the end of the `for` loop, `input` is the greatest element of that type, and it is inserted in the back.

[It lives!](http://ideone.com/Qv2gih)

Case matters in this comparison (`'a' != 'A'`) but if it shouldn't matter, adding a fix for that is easy.

Comment: Sorry, but where does the vector named sorted come from?

Comment: @Jeremy I realized I left that out and I edited the variable declarations in. Maybe you need to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#include "iostream"
#include "algorithm"
#include "string"
#include "vector"
#include "cctype"
#include "unordered_map"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> all, s;
    vector <int> n;
    unordered_map <int, bool> number;
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);
    int prev=0;
    for (int i=0; i<x.length(); i++)
    {
        if (x[i]==' ')
        {
            all.push_back(x.substr(prev, i-prev+1));
            prev=i+1;
        }
    }
    all.push_back(x.substr(prev));
    for (int i=0; i<all.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(all[i].c_str()[0]) || isdigit(all[i].c_str()[1]))
        {
            n.push_back(atoi(all[i].c_str()));
            number[i]=1;
        }
        else s.push_back(all[i]);
    }
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    sort(n.begin(), n.end());
    for (int i=0, j=0, k=0; i<all.size(); i++)
    {
        if (number[i]) cout << n[j++] << ' ';
        else cout << s[k++] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks better this way, but please mention if you cannot predict the number of elements beforehand, I will modify the code accordingly.

Comment: I can't predict the number of elements